# How to access querystrings from URL in android using appcelerator

Tags: android, appcelerator

I am implementing OAUTH in android using appcelerator. login page is redirecting to response page with token appended to query string e.g. http://mysite.com?access_token="token"

So I need to fetch this query string using appcelerator.

I have used Ti.App.getArguments() 
but this api is only working for ios not for android.

Is there any api available for fetching query string in appcelerator that works in android??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event listener to the webview like so:

```
webview.addEventListener('load', function(e){
    var url = e.url.split('?');
    var urlParams = url[1];
});
```

The variable urlParams will contain a string that looks like `param1=value1&param2=value2` so from there you just need to split them up and find the `access_token` param.

Comment: thanks I have already figured out this solution and yeah it works.